# keytool does not understand -cacerts

Tags: java, maven, keytool

I am behind a firewall using Maven to resolve dependencies for my Java projects.
When getting the error message from Maven "*... transfer failed for https://something ...*"
I used to open https://something in a browser, save the certificate to a .cer-file and use
`keytool -importcert -cacerts -alias <some-alias> -file <.cer-file> -storepass changeit`.
After that procedure, Maven usually can find the repo for download.

But now I get the error message from keytool *unknown Option: -cacerts*.

I guess I could substitute -cacerts by `-keystore the-keystore-file`, but I do not know how to find the file that is used by Maven or by the JDK Maven is using.

What can I do so that Maven finds the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Could find a solution: The keystore Maven is using, is that of the JDK, which is *$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts*.
Substituting `-cacerts` by `-keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` in the `keytool` command above solved my problem.

Still: why is the keytool option *-cacerts* not working for me? It is documented all over but does not pop up with `keytool -help -importcert`.

Comment: `-cacerts` was first supported by keytool, in JDK 9.  If you are on JDK 8, then you need to use `-keystore` . [documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#keytool_option_importcert)